# how to login this web site by php curl?

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I'm trying to log in here that http://www.wemakeprice.com/  by curl, but i don't know what where send data for login and where i get receve to login cookie

some site is easy because can see where send to login form data by network tap in Developer Tools

but that site is cen't find where i send data for login.

i'm looking for Helpful document about this Problem

can you give me advice?

Thanks for look.

Comment: perform the login on the site with a network inspector/packet inspector open. You will see the endpoint and the post data that is sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet I wrote, replace username and password with your corresponding credentials, and replace the URL with the page you want to grab data from (a page that requires a login).

Check the post data that is sent in browser inspector. Replace $postinfo with the correct post data to ensure you are sending the right data. "email" and "Password" as the $postdata might not work for the site you are trying to login into. If you have trouble, post the inspector's data that is reported in the network tab and I'll try and help.

```
    $username = "email@example.com";
    $password = "MyPassword123";

    $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ctemp";

    $path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'MyTempCookie');

    $url = "https://www.example.com/dashboard/";
    $postinfo = "email=".$username."&Password=".$password;

    $cookie_file_path = $path."/cookie.txt";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
    //for certain features, set the cookie the site has - this is optional
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
    curl_exec($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $html_data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $html_data;
```

Here at the end I'm simply just echoing the return html data. But you can do whatever you want with it and search for the data inside the response that you need.

**Edit:**
Just saw that the site has a recaptcha for their login process. Logging in via cURL is going to be far more complex now since they present the recaptcha code to you in an image. Might want to look into tutorials on spoofing recaptcha data. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I am studying now with your code